# Android PayPal integration without card.io?

Tags: android, paypal, card.io

I use [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) to integrate PayPal payments in my app and it works fine. I am wondering, can I disable "card.io" support (where a user scan the credit card)? And as a result remove 4MB of .so "card.io" libs files? I cannot find any information on that neither on the official PayPal site nor Google.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff Brateman commented, there is a [newly added section](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md#disabling-cardio-card-scanning) on this matter:

> **Disabling card.io card scanning**
>
> Future payments does not require card.io card scanning, so it is safe to remove the camera scanner libraries by removing the following folders within the `lib` directory: `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, `mips`, and `x86`.
>
> Single Payments can be configured to accept credit cards through manual entry, but without card scanning.  To do so, remove the same libs above, and remove `android.permission.CAMERA` and `android.permission.VIBRATE` permissions from `AndroidManifest.xml`.  If you wish to disable credit card support altogether, follow the above steps to reduce the permissions and sdk footprint, and add the following to the `PayPalConfiguration` initialization:
>
> `config.acceptCreditCards(false);`

Comment: I am working on  Paypal android SDK first time and I am getting error on this"PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD".Seems it is not available .I am using demo code from github

Comment: I just edited this post to reflect the 2.0 changes, as specified in @user1007522's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you disable that **pay with card** button , use this

```
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD, true);
```

Comment: Ok, but does this mean I can remove ".so" dependencies?

Comment: @MaksimSorokin does this comment help? https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/24#issuecomment-28314349

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder, thanks! Do you know if there is any "official" documentation on that?

Comment: @MaksimSorokin, please see our [GitHub readme](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md#disabling-cardio-card-scanning) for a newly added section about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In the new SDK you need to do this like this:

```
PayPalConfiguration() object = new PayPalConfiguration();
object = object.acceptCreditCards(false);
```

and then give object on the intent like this:

```
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, object);
```